# iOS app crashes when launched on external device but works fine on simulator. "code signature invalid for"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

Every time I build/run the app on the Xcode simulator the app works fine. Once I plugin my iPhone to test the app it crashes with a SIGABPT.

***OUTPUT***

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/LLV1
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase'

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase: stat() failed with errno=25
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23983622-E659-443F-B061-3EAABABC0BA8/LLV1.app/Frameworks/CodableFirebase.framework/CodableFirebase: stat() failed with errno=1
```

*List of things I have tried.*

1. Changing pod file and adding "use_modular_headers!"
2. Restarting XCode
3. Restarting computer
4. Changing Code Signing Identity in Build Settings

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  What version of iOS is on your device?  Are you using a free developer membership?

Comment: Xcode Version 11.3, iOS 13.3.1 Yes I am using a free developer membership.